# cast iron: what kind is it?

Tags: terminology

I need to use a word for a kind of iron which is not malleable (I mean which fractures if bent) and cannot be moulded. I have tried my best to find it but I couldn't. Someone told me 'cast iron'. Is this right? Cast iron, as I've read, doesn't get shaped but is hard though. I am looking for a word for that kind of iron which is breakable.

Comment: "iron which is not solid"?  Do you mean "molten iron"?  All iron is solid at room temperature.

Comment: No, i mean which fractures if bent

Comment: Okay.  You have misunderstood the word "solid".   Solid means "not fluid".  Glass, and steel are both solid.

Answer (score 5):

That is indeed cast iron. as the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cast_iron) says:

> Cast iron tends to be brittle, except for malleable cast irons. With its relatively low melting point, good fluidity, castability, excellent machinability, resistance to deformation and wear resistance, cast irons have become an engineering material with a wide range of applications and are used in pipes, machines and automotive industry parts, such as cylinder heads, cylinder blocks and gearbox cases. It is resistant to damage by oxidation but is difficult to weld.

Cast iron is hard, it is shaped when it is cast into a mold, or later by machining, but not by bending or (usually) welding.  It can be broken, being brittle.

Metaphorically, cast iron is something which is rigid and unchangeable, or which can only change by being destroyed.  "Break, but bend not" might be said of something that is cast iron. A "cast iron guarantee" is one with no room for variation.

Answer (score 4):

[Cast iron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cast_iron) is so called because you can cast it by melting it and pouring it into a mould. That means that, once cast, it is *always* solid and *always* moulded.

What makes steel different from cast iron is that it is [malleable](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/malleable)- it can be shaped by hammering (think of a blacksmith making a horse shoe or a sword) or pressing (think of making a bodywork panel for a car).

Cast iron is hard and brittle: if you hit it hard enough, it will crack and splinter.

When you use the expression **cast iron** metaphorically about something else, it has very specific meanings: about a guarantee or an alibi it means "absolutely certain to be effective and will not fail", and about anything else, it means "very strong".